# How would I create an entry page which redirects to different urls?

Tags: php

I have a script, which creates urls like this:

```
domain.com/model/sunny-leone-123.html
domain.com/model/stoya-24.html
domain.com/model/kagney-linn-karter-2.html
```

These numbers start from 1 and increase as new models get added. They are always the same for the same models, so this does not change.

I would like to create an age verification entry page, something like this:

```
domain.com/enter.php
```

and this could be combined with something like this:

```
domain.com/enter.php?m=sunny-leone
domain.com/enter.php?m=stoya
domain.com/enter.php?m=kagney-linn-karter
```

When people would click on any of these, they would go to the age verification page, and get redirected to a certain model page, after clicking "Yes, I am 18", or something like this.

The script code for it looks something like this:

```
<? $link = generateUrl('model', $row['name'], $row['record_num']); ?>
```

and urls get output with rewrite rules in .htaccess file.

So in general, I would need to do something like this with php:

a) get the parameter from the url 
b) look it up in the database (this would be the number that was added, I guess) c) construct target url based on this 
d) redirect people to this after clicking yes

I am familiar with php, but I have not worked on this too much, so I am not sure how to construct it and what functions would I use.

---

Edit:

I have some more info here, maybe somebody would be able to suggest the best way to go.

1) Starting ulrs will look something like this:

domain.com/e.php?m=sunny-leone (so I will need to store everything after the equal sign in a variable I would say, and obtain it with GET, most likely)

2) Then search for "sunny-leone" in the database, which looks like this:

http://prntscr.com/982yph

This is in table named "models" and column names are "name" and "record_num"

The url parameter is "sunny-leone", and the record in the database would be "Sunny Leone", so I would need to make sure I will convert that to the right format or search for it in a certain way.

After it finds "Sunny Leone", it needs to match it to the "record_num" and create a url like this:

domain.com/model/"name"-"record_num".html (and the "name" part would contain hyphens like "sunny-leone"

So if record number for "Sunny Leone" would be "123" the url would be looking like this:

domain.com/model/sunny-leone-123.html

3) And this needs to be connected to the Yes button, as a link. People will see "Are you 18 or older"? -> They will click yes, and it needs to go to this url.

I guess this is the best way to do it, get the model name from the entry page url, search for it in the database, construct the url from this, and make it work with the yes button.

Comment: You mean this [Kagney Linn Karter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kagney_Linn_Karter) ? I'd even raise the age to 21... Besides, why not use some sort of session and create the redirections based on the choice (18 or not).

Comment: @LeviZoesch Right you are, now it is wikipedia and the guys of 18 and older will find their way alone.

Comment: @AaronSmith You will need to use $_GET, then you will need to query the db table, if exists then build the url.

Comment: @Levi Zoesch - Thanks, this helps a lot. Some keywords / general ideas, and I can research further in Google and try to figure it out based on this. This, this and that, use this loop, this function, and it will be easy to get it together in one piece.

Comment: @AaronSmith Instead of reinventing the wheel, have a look into PHP frameworks like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) or [Slim](http://slimframework.com).